# Screen not turning off after screen timeout in 20.04

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver, timeout

I have this problem where the screen doesn't completely turn off and just fades to black with the pointer visible after the set time in GNOME's settings panel.

It looks like this:
[image]

Is there any fix for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, as reported here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/996770). It might be worth to reopen and provide additional information. But is also seems like a low priority bug. Just an aesthetic issue. Are you able to log back in and use your computer without problems after this happens?

Comment: For me, this occasionally happens when a user is logged in. And yes, I'm able to resume my work just fine after moving the mouse or pressing any keys to get to the lock screen.

Comment: I'd suggest you follow up on that bug or open a new case. There isn't much else to do I think. It's on the Gnome + Ubuntu team to squash these bugs. You could change the settings so the computer doesn't go to sleep, manually lock screen it, or try a different desktop environment. I suggest KDE if you are interested in trying a new desktop.